# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] I can't figure out why my file path does not exist

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using python to write some code in a tensorflow google colab notebook.

I am stuck with this error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv' does not exist: b'/home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv'

Here is the problematic snippet of code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import functools

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn

#load the data from local file into a dataframe
path = '/home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df.head()
```

And just to confirm I do have the right path,

```
(base) brandon@brandon:~/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train$ find $PWD -type f | grep "Y_10KHz_left.csv"
```

```
/home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv
```

Comment: Looks weird that you're getting an error with a byte literal vs just a regular string. Try a `type` on path?  Or try converting your path to raw strings? (`r'/home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv'`)

Comment: Kilohertz should be kHz not KHz. Anyway, seriously, you gave a snippet of code, but please, you have to extract and provide a [mcve], just to make sure that it's not in the part of the code you didn't show. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If you try a plain `open()` on that file path, what happens?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for the reply, the software that im using automatically names the file with 'KHz'. I edited the question an entered all the code.

Comment: @zhqiat when using a raw string i get the same error.

Comment: Please clarify that further: Is it the last line that emits the error or the one before? Also, which of all the import statements are really necessary? Removing possibly irrelevant things helps concentrating on the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for the existence of the file before attempting to read from it.

```
import os

#load the data from local file into a dataframe
file_path = '/home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv'
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    df.head()
else:
    print(f"Unable to find the file at {file_path}")
```

Comment: How does this help solve the real problem?  He's just going to get his own error message telling him the file doesn't exist, instead of the system error message.

Comment: @JohnGordon You should never open something without checking if it exists first. Based on his error he's passing a byte string, when he passes it to os.path it should complain about it.

Comment: @JohnGordon
Thanks for the reply, using the method you suggested this is what i get
"Unable to find the file at /home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv"

Comment: @brandondjuric If you type `cat /home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv` what does it return?

Comment: @JohnGordon unfortunately - Unable to find the file at cat /home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv

Comment: Well then the file definitely doesn't exist at that location so no wonder your code can't find it. Type `pwd` from whatever directory you have your .csv in and paste it here

Comment: The file does exist at the specified location
brandon@brandon:~/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train$ pwd
/home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Josh, I think you misinterpreted brandon's earlier reply.  It looks like he used `cat /home/brandon/...` as the _filename_; he didn't type that as a _command_.

Comment: @JoshCorreia ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: @JohnGordon  upon typing cat /home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv the terminal returns the contents of the csv file

Comment: Well, that's really odd.  How are you running the python code?  Is it running as some user account other than yourself?

Comment: @JohnGordon It is not running as another user. I have tried running the code in a Google Colab Notebook as well as from gedit.

Comment: Can you try running a different python script that just has `open('/home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv')` and see if you get the same error?

Comment: So, this boils down your question to why some file exists but `os.path.exists()` returns false, in particular the relation to tensorflow is resolved. Stupid thing I'd check: Take the path to the file from the commandline, i.e. `sys.argv`. What I'm suspecting is that some character that is not visible is used by the shell invocation due to autocompletion perhaps. Another thing I'd like to know is how exactly you invoke the example program, i.e. the commandline you use to call it.

Comment: @JoshCorreia, I disagree with checking whether the file exists before trying to opening it. Simple reason is that this presents a race condition, i.e. something in between could have deleted the file. I'd rather try to open it and if it fails, I'd try to figure out why it failed (which may again be subject to race conditions). But that's just a nit and has little to do with this case.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 import os

    #load the data from local file into a dataframe
    file_path = '/home/brandon/Desktop/AnomalyDetection/Code/train/Y_10KHz_left.csv'

    if file_full_path:
         file_path, file_name = os.path.split(file_full_path)
         print(file_path, file_name)
        try:
             data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(file_path, file_name))
             print(data)
         except Exception as e:
             print(f"error: {e}")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, adding some comment to explain why it works would increase the long term value of the answer